# How do i encrypt email columns in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, encryption

I have a rails 3 application which uses mysql. The app stores phone numbers and emails of customers in a table. I would like to encrypt the fields instead of storing them as plain and straight values. This way, the table is rendered useless to anyone even if he/she gets access to the db.

But there is another problem. The records are queried a lot using email and phone number, and are indexed. How can I achieve encrypting the fields without affecting the performance and still be able to search and match easily?

Answer (score 5):

First, remember that if someone gets enough access to read your code files, he will probably get your decryption routine and key - your encryption will only protect you against attackers that get access to the database and nothing else.

If you want to search for partial mail addresses and phone numbers using MySQL, you cannot use encryption - if the data is encrypted in a way MySQL can't read it, then, well, MySQL can't read and thus can't search it.

However, you could do the following:

- Hash the data and store the hash in column "email_hash"
- Encrypt the data and store it in a second column "email_crypt"

If you want to look for the row with e-mail X, you select where email_hash = hash(X). If you want to know the e-mail address of a row, you select email_crypt and decrypt it.

However, this would allow attackers to test whether a certain e-mail is in your database (i.e. they could bruteforce the hashes). To prevent this, you should use a HMAC method for hashing and keep the key secret.

You could now think "Hey, I can skip the hash and do lookups by encrypting the plain e-mail address and looking for a row containing the same encrypted string". No, you cannot do that. If you encrypt data, you use a random "IV" which you store together with the data, to ensure that if you encrypt the same data twice, you get different results. You could set the IV to a constant value, but that is a non-standard way of using cryptography and could cause security issues, so don't do that. Also, use a proper chaining mode, e.g. AES-CBC.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Encryption** : You need to have Symmetric Encryption (AES). Ensure that you encrypt your encryption key (call it Data Encryption Key) with a Master Encryption key.
2. **Fast Query and Retrieval**: You need to also have one-way hashed values of email and phone number in your table. Generate Hash (SHA-1) or (MD5) before issuing search on the table.

Comment: Drop a comment if you want me to expand my answers. Keeping them short because I am not entirely sure of the requirements/usage.

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. I have one doubt though, is there a way to query using partial matching of one-way hashed fields?

Comment: Changing a single character (even case) will completely change the hash. you could also hash a portion of the email to do partial matching, but your functionality will be limited. You will still have to decrypt the fields to do complete partial matching.

Comment: That would be a problem. Because prefixes of email and phone numbers would result in altogether different hash value. There would be no co-relation between hash of prefix and actual email/phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier to do in MySQL. You can use either simple MySQL's [ENCODE/DECODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encode) functions
or Advanced functions like `AES_DECRYPT()` or `AES_ENCRYPT()`.

See all the function list is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.htm).

**Note:** Whatever you use make sure you store a salt in a column against this row. And store another salt in your application configuration file. This will make the encryption using dynamic salt and you can keep part of the salt secret too. It'll be tough for attacker to retrieve those.